# Open Office Extension getting the Value of a Textfield from the settingspage

Tags: java, plugins, textfield, openoffice.org

I am currently working on an Open Office Extension and I have some troubles at one point.
I have made a settingspage in the OpenOffice Writer Tab with 3 Textfields.
I now want to get the Text the user entered into this fields.

I tried this:

```
    XControl textfield2 = _xControlCont.getControl("TextField2");


    XTextComponent username = (XTextComponent) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextComponent.class, textfield2);


    passwd = password.getText();
```

I am getting a Nullpointer exception right at the beginning and I think that the Problem is that with this code i cant get the value of the Textfield when the Optionspage is not open.

I am running kinda the same code in a seperate class where I test if all entered values are correct and if you can connect to our server. 
I tried to get the Code from there with a getter method but this didn´t work too.

here is an example:

```
    @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    boolean testConnection = false;
    XControl label = _xControlCont.getControl("Label4");
    XFixedText xLabel = (XFixedText) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XFixedText.class, label);


    XControl textfield2 = _xControlCont.getControl("TextField2");



    XTextComponent username = (XTextComponent) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextComponent.class, textfield2);



    user = username.getText();}
```

and then outside of this method i am using the getter. 
This is the Exception I am getting:

> Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.openoffice.demo.DocumentUpload.run(DocumentUpload.java:56)

I hope that one of you can help me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this code worked: `passwd = password.getText();`.  Please post the code where the problem occurred.  Also what is the error message or incorrect behavior? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: added The exception.

Comment: Please post the full exception message that shows where the error occurred.  Also where is `_xControlCont` defined?  Perhaps it does not have a control called `TextField2`.  If possible, write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openoffice.demo.DocumentUpload.run(DocumentUpload.java:56)

Comment: Which one is line 56?

Comment: line 56 is the first line at the first example

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `_xControlCont` is null.  Be sure that the code always creates the object before it is used.

There is an example of using an `XControlContainer` at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Groovy/Office/RuntimeDialog.

**EDIT**:

Do not access a text field when the page is not open.  Instead, save the text field's string to a variable when the page is open.  Then read the saved string later.

Depending on the code, the string could also be saved to persistent storage such as [user field variables](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Variables) or a data file, or returned as an argument from a dialog window.  For example:

```java
optionsDialog.doExecute()
results = optionsDialog.getResults()
```

Comment: Yes I know but how can i create it ? I tried it several ways but it just wont work. It seems like the Plugin is just not able to get the Textfields when the  OptionsPage is not opened.